# How to call PHP function from Javascript (ideally without AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Don't really know AJAX that well.. Here is the issue.

I am reading a database within the PHP function that populate some global variables, I can access the variables ok, but I need the php function to be called regularly.

```
<?php

function thatIwant()
{
  //read database
 return 10;
}

echo("
<script>

function refreshDiv()
    {
     //// this is where I need to call the above function.
     var refresher = setTimeout('refreshDiv()', 2000);
    }
</script>
");
?>
```

Comment: You must use AJAX. Client-side code can't call server-side code except through an HTTP request.

Comment: _"Don't really know AJAX that well."_ [That is fairly easily remedied.](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

Comment: Also, calling `setTimeout` with a string parameter is bad practice. Use a function reference: `var refresher = setTimout(refreshDiv, 2000);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a PHP function regularly from Javascript without the use of an XmlHttpRequest. PHP is executed when the page is first requested. With an XHR, you could do the following:

```
function refreshDiv() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById("refreshDiv").innerHTML = 
xhr.responseText;
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET", "yourPHPEndpoint.php", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }, 1000);
}
```

This would allow you to query your PHP file continuously, and update the contents of the div with the result of the query. This can also be done through jQuery with `$.ajax` or `$.get`.

Comment: Thanks for this - would the above code just be used like any other function in JS.

Comment: @SamBrown Just add it in a `<script>` block. When it works, be sure to accept an answer. Hope this was helpful!

Comment: How can I use the above code in my function refreshDiv()

Comment: Also what is yourDiv for in code

Comment: @SamBrown You don't need to, but you can just copy it into `refreshDiv`. Make sure you only call it once, though, because it's creating a timeout that will fire on its own once a second.

Comment: @SamBrown Your question is a duplicate. You will find much better answers on the duplicate post.

Comment: I have been looking - not getting anywhere really.

Comment: @SamBrown I've updated the code for the `refreshDiv` function.

Comment: A shame no more up votes here. First  because indeed the availability of the XmlHttpRequest() has made it possible to do something that previously could only be done except as an http request from an anchor <a> tag, and second because of all the negative "you can't do that without AJAX" answers to similar questions, peppered throughout the internet. A hearty thanks to @furkle for the confirmation, as I've been doing this for a while and was worried I was missing a serious 'why not" restriction.

Comment: Very bad example, not the right variable names and "XmlHttpRequest" is also wrong written. Better example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4033310/8283938